# Did a moderator erase my answer incorrectly?

Tags: discussion

[I answered a question on Tablet K](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9728/what-issues-exist-with-the-tablet-k-hecksher) with a link to a blog. It was erased due to "stories heard through the grapevine".

However, the blog post I linked is a first-person account under a real name. The person is [easily verifiable online](https://www.instagram.com/thechaviva/?hl=en). This is not a story heard through the grapeline, but an Eid Echad account who is just as believable, if not more so than a kosher symbol, and thus halchically valid. It should not have been erased, as it is not a rumor but a first-person account of someone who experienced tablet-k's unreliability first hand. I believe the answer should be restored.

Answer is below:

> Regarding the ability to execute his policies:
>
> *Just Call Me Chaviva* (AKA *Kvetching Editor*) describes when a Tablet-K certified institution served ***CATFISH*** and no response
> was taken!
>
> > It turns out the hecksher is Tablet K, the rabbi is Rabbi Rafael Saffra, and the kitchen is only open for kosher food during the
> > summer. This means that the folks running the kitchen have only 7
> > prior weeks from summer 2008 under their belt, are not trained in
> > kosher cooking, and that -- perhaps worst of all -- there was no
> > mashgiach in the MEAT kitchen. The rabbi visits the campus at the
> > beginning of each summer (which means he's visited all of twice), and
> > gives all of his advice and guidance on kashrut from a great distance.
> > **Basically, Tablet K took the money and ran, which appears to be their M.O.** We also found out that the guy who makes all the food
> > realized, almost instantly, that the fish wasn't kosher. Making it
> > fishy (har har) that he even made the product. I'm guessing this is
> > why it was packaged separately for our consuming pleasure. The campus
> > rabbi was less than excited to help or discuss the issue, and he was
> > of no help in the situation. I expressed a desire for the kitchen to
> > be rekashered -- that was the only way I'd eat anything out of the
> > kitchen. **I was told that it WAS rekashered (though without
> > supervision by ANYONE).** The rabbi didn't offer to rekasher, and
> > neither did the school.
>
> The full article is [here](http://www.kvetchingeditor.com/2009/08/kosher-catfish-i-think-not.html). Read it and you'll never eat Tablet-K
> again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it was deleted incorrectly.

The laws of "eid echad" are not relevant here. There's an unverified story in a blog post about some sort of summer camp that allegedly was under the hashgacha in question but apparently the rabbi was not present at the kitchen. The attendee at the program is apparently very upset at the organizers. What does this tell us factually about this hashgacha? Pretty much nothing. Should you attend a summer program organized by this school? Probably not.

We don't even know what the hashgacha was hired to do and hence we can only guess about their ability to execute their policies.

This is exactly the kind of partial-information story which I believe falls squarely in the intended exclusion of "through the grapevine". There are no objective facts.

Comment: There is a first person report of a story in a university - not a summer camp.
Did you read the story? It states that Tablet K.was the supervision agency. In addition the story is verified by the author of the post - the eid echad.

Comment: http://www.kvetchingeditor.com/2009/08/kosher-catfish-i-think-not.html

Comment: It's shocking that you would delete the answer without reading the linked article.

Comment: I don't see why the exact nature of the program ("university" vs "summer camp") is relevant. Again, "eid echad" is not a relevant construct that you need to be discussing it.

Comment: Eid echad Newman beissurim is the reason we trust Kashrut. How is it not relevant?

Comment: It's not the standard sought in the question.

Comment: It is not through the grapevine. It a a first person personal account.

Comment: @TheAsh it is exactly the kind of partial-information story which I believe falls squarely in the intended exclusion of "through the grapevine".

Comment: I believe through the grapevine means hearsay. You are redefining the phrase, against what it actually means.

Comment: It clearly falls under "Ability of the organization to execute on those policies". It's a first person account that confirms the inability.

Comment: It's a first person account that tells a story where they allegedly didn't execute on the narrator's expectations. Be precise and you'll see why this isn't the sort of objective facts sought in the question. For all we know the kitchen wasn't under official hashgacha and the hillel rabbi (or whoever was organizing things there) just asked them for some initial advice and misrepresented things to your eid achat. As I said, "we don't even know what the hashgacha was hired to do and hence we can only guess about their ability to execute their policies."